# "Grouped expression is missing ')'", except it isn't

Tags: regex, visual-studio, find

Using VS2010's find dialog, I'm using the following regex: `(?'outer'^div\#.+) input$`.

I'm trying to create a named group of "outer" with the contents `div#someId` from `div#someId input` (in this case where `someId` matches `.+`)

However, Visual Studio is presenting the dialog: `Grouped expression is missing ')'`.

However, the `)` is there after the `+`. What am I escaping or failing to escape?

**EDIT:**

I don't necessarily need to used named groupings, I just need to be able to use `div#someId` in the replace to add another selector.

Comment: Are you using the productivity power tools?

Comment: @SLaks Yes, they're installed. I've updated the question, since it may be possible to solve what I need without getting the named group working.

Comment: @SLaks `(^div\#.+ )input` with a space inside the grouping, doesn't even let me replace with `\1\` as a back reference for the contents of the parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Visual Studio's find and replace uses braces `{ }` and not parentheses `( )` for backreferences and named references.

---

Since someone may find this trying to use [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)/[named grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) in a Find and Replace in Visual Studio, here's an example of using them:

To replace

```
div#someId input
```

with

```
div#someId input,
div#someId textarea
```

Find: `{^div\#.+ }input` and replace with: `\0,\n\1textarea`

It will put `div#someId` (with the space, which matches `^div\#.+` into the first backreference.

**Building the replace string with a backreference:**
The replace will then replace the whole string :`\0`

```
div#someId input
```

then a comma: `,`

```
div#someId input,
```

then a new line: `\n`

```
div#someId input,
```

then the first group: `\1`

```
div#someId input,
div#someId
```

then the given text: `textarea`

```
div#someId input,
div#someId textarea
```

Altogether makes the replace string `\0,\n\1textarea`

**Update:** Based on this [MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/23b0eac0-b2a1-4573-b96a-7f92223b2e2b) in VS2012 backreferences are accessed using `$n` rather than `\n`, so the replace string would be: `$0,\n$1textarea`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Productivity Power Tools' inline Replace feature, which uses standard .Net regexes

Comment: Is that just `Ctrl+H` that brings up the smaller dialog at the top of the editor pane? Or is it something else? I'm doing this across multiple files in a particular folder, so needed the Find and Replace dialog to specify file types and folders.

Comment: Just `Ctrl+H`.  You can select Current Project or Entire Solution, but you can't select arbitrary folders.

Comment: Ah, if I need this on a single file I'll do that then, good to know regexes are enabled on it.